# Youtube - understanding debug trace text

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, youtube

I had the below output (along with monkey with a hammer picture at the right)  when I tried opening youtube on chromium. I was wondering how the lengthy output aids google engineers in debugging rather than a screenshot.

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>
> A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this
>   situation.
>
> If you see them, send them this information as text (screenshots
>   frighten them):
>       APCGX7qycD8BRvqozjCuAupL2ggiqnNJ1EsrpiaYPzWXju4RMoCg7Npp
>       AJqjgxc7PGoiyYTEmoJGn2JVvEbyAVDPMvvqGi1GF4DtQX-86Vky3FfR
>       CH-eUDuTpaa9Jrlk16e2-OOOfEZ3i4wMFb3skJdRtBGPh9nMlnq3UbL1
>       DCxj8wGM4JyUzWhi8gxbJeshXkuTeHwWtZ0iVKwV1YohiQlMLuNgIqzw
>       J73G-dI0G2vOBMvQGCyQgEUUVUOOpmv4XphggiLg1USeyJ-28GurSbqd
>       2C9a3nitWqfzUYwnBmEaHCE-rnuYOr6qplmTBFrUZOWl7vB0204fxuvR
>       PX0WWFgz__GFVzGVhUKnn57nyAOuUsPN6z9rHz6QPPUwdJ566jQcbxQC
>       bmjVhb86wjfatpKSdjKT8jhk_P6SBEbpwJeNS2udXG2he55GRwM-3P6-
>       JjNAU0Ayh0buv_h-QV6zQ8DiYpmp0Lkx-1JZtT-P5Nwrje8V_viOU4K3
>       bl_ixYW7Be2O_IsskWP2YtvXHmhJaOb451Zswzh2izjDcqrVUO-LsxZk
>       DgIgSRcDsPLurn-6f6bsl_mQ6Y1JvZGIo5pvWiNdyogCfEGrAVSq-jEb
>       TrrKY8LJpVaRgJ8Idx2QUZDt6CZ-c-2qScEVQHvUpoA9SPNmytBunFUE
>       eS9NR1HbSH_Q1nzZWXnvuIWN-IQ25zAW0Awfq0-GAoFeZGpa8fHiLMwU
>       lTyWettPjJbbdJmsn8u9_Qit7CIaCZ1QiMNk_aBJagrj4Bwhe-ghLsqh
>       n8Hod9P6nrYQvSBegqcFXXOfsUaV1-Ue4KhibkhwNhse-N3K7p_5e4jn
>       7DGdORpAri_9XIXeC6lIAo7ZnweijyPqXIRGxCgunJCxVvALmIx8t6me
>       Y-YW7ww7066U-CocEzK9GFmD5URqPPE86ajiKbSIbS3rEfIpAPc7VNjW
>       xoL_VUnznBA6TmSreQRJso2JQTni0DixVKCnFxafjGLn2GKYAI6VSvjn
>       K_lfujqSS9HNeotAfucJWgzh5P4X46DfyxZ6GusP20MPM3s8G1qh1ZqV
>       YMh-Ae7f3veMT1TGxkr0vDwewb1OQgdHb4VSCAaRA-0TRGGdjtX-_1Mn
>       K6lA6j1IDnDR-MgToqss4T5DPMsom8GKVdnDCgAYVI3CHQKg2zFSriC8
>       ZRi-G4laQpCaRAP10JVfD7eha0Xn6dn_m_XCGRafttgHgWYw9CGiA4yt
>       Z4xEjmcohEPL7Ie_OfbG9Tz15HWGtXIZQSc9RujtVwwo8NhX3HEhl5pe
>       3pyQW3gOAYaZF6b2RuXugLXSheI4L7ZhkI_bf458oN4iO6LS-LdTSTYB
>       XyR_4PBSG0qrmWPUiuMPk_qOtJNjGY1kqVdfwS0Z9dfWWtnDo38AjQoa
>       B4irGjp6aG321cXvI3HuE9v7nt7tVW2psig4h9g6HN5e4Q7v9YWtdIQZ
>       j4_MRXlMXcIqdNM9i9khQHxZZLM73xwNIMENwqhi7UT1EqT19onkVAFV
>       y96eIJspImmOprJuVoA2OZ2UsjVGYrSXHZTHCFywKPzy2vU0TiGVk6G6
>       kjib1PcIKDagEXN-a9y_0YllxaYByZ5wWNK6XCBSm6Ys7a3Cbj6cUsTo
>       bAyLouN0lkKqAq_WqGSHWqU-7ncUi7yflz7tzKh9U5IFajcn8I5j74eS
>       KbNzyQpPh7eAXBMoyn6zXJN7rf8C3dP1HIwBbC42ZYNCKnv8sKBR86IA
>       1k6Y1bKM9fcCBGwADnME3dGwsZpum3AtvLx_i6OP8VglOZjb-BcAQQAl
>       icbDkJTAbd8clRjFpkqKiScQuzMdTZFkVf6NC6WSAJ1M6kLU2mCOSGp6
>       nASyAj7jKDh6xtgCDF_NWLh_KfCR_v1y-pVIepn3_50bbyNkbuAoN8z2
>       GKXAOZG9ZRFHpQ7V2FFbt8HrXXoCYnVDidbFoRRdnPiUaDzMOwBYc1qW
>       4ArjAYg-2Np_H_fJapb-75w--mnGQRldLnPJQ2TiutCozjQnqRm8PIZ0
>       eAALVq_z1AtE5qOsAkROSMEGiKcpKxF7G72PPgti511LPlYvZ4K6dAYK
>       mpMPFZZKrWyehgOa7PvHX-hzWXK1ds-DDxugkfKVImDUWCqyIUbkdeRc
>       kQJShl3eGc8cc4tyOIR9hrkeuHpiGiCocV9yusI4iEMmc-0mt-17ihsM
>       0l-xuxhtx_V4d_pdHuAwQwloQwVg-KL39jW9Et_y2NKtkgXZIjaUdoW8
>       I8WvATN1q-F_RMVoiMubX_-V18IlMGl98fd9MPB6oeSp6zZ_LGy5hwsZ
>       UuWy0FKmpssebG3OcaxDVz93hnlSN0DpQ7Wd1flD6dVEi_eacHF1VqSf
>       DoRHSQvPqLaHjsuN6EMUT_2z-Fj6BNTKWEN1PFjPxUCoqcN5LjDYM332
>       okB-ufNwjzagWZieRHLmhi57kjCpPGerWjN0PCeyxpQkiaDAG15Zgu1_
>       5_O0p7jbpwh4sEuvVlwxdaFnDWxzmjFZr8ntT1PTEDylqO72Goft74w7
>       ZnPbm48TPyQebHAqrZcamDor16KJqQTDXKYmwxgy-VDFDp2_uml-sK68
>       6zTMRNnU1XEQtkYnT8JrDBocI8OJgcQti7iXpJu6XkgRRrUdyyhY6KMO
>       zTaOCDazYlkX38U0FccBuR99MXzD9iXOp6hf_MNksHKysv4No3LpomYa
>       cjsHCrWuB5upVSLHx-e3bULAYxW1ttT_b0RVkqpKYiEyGTtzaacUhvHB
>       47Ti8LYSwZAB3eggA7DzBTQnu0DU6JZvuMsO-5m2VRsBiEwa8lvUm1Le
>       DHWnn7NQnjZnfjXgmDeMr-wt1olPm5Es-o2T0f7-Zd5qU3uX9mh0u1nW
>       0PcNFCY268sWJw_9ehRk7iFnDcbOGEtQMRiBybYQziyK6iaSRj9OYRkC
>       ZbnP2aYAPApjNh9jeOxX4XEeVa5uusvb3UvThkNt6j0l2YNW4kdZUIxl
>       L0uZqzZuBXqTH6NX_FL1KkeBe2aMJvRnL5VqvbctZeq-aGAdsnshWEp0
>       9RAdUIghql9u_eOm8PBBdSH3bPr4ubpfm4za4jztFFuk2iIoewmjOP8I
>       cBt9Ur8S9Cjna8iNxGYLdnWXAs7Gt2H5WTWpDrefyPRY3GCWOq7_24NH
>       8AilGTYG9eFlzcMQX4QTyVenqSwujEGJRif0ZxSK6KOd4giubx_EUhL5
>       -Xwm0eXX46z9cFbJE0flM979iKP5rXQGLncgA8dR9FtbQx5BxJfLMCkv
>       6rgm_LIo4dPYvOpYyslvWv9e948ejjqfNDXyjdeST5ZXoFyiaOcN5DM_
>       _kCLquYQXWEYRSW71PrCjI-_OFMkEYRf_EIVJDZCrO6GxDPqGdrHI7u9
>       Rn4AuD48enhHWZj6mDSnQnEtn91w68gJK9OAIbnBW1FEAFXkuQ8kB1UO
>       Kc51mz-RgnEgSHf0-me6o_nTadLDPyaWvz00EKutRz8MKGzyngfEkmU2
>       3VG9sbPX7QsIvUjjbM_pJOl9lnr1L84-Ntbl_EP7kj04MqPCsoFxyogO
>       M6dLlDt9p3E54J4fJglw2yB9KoK1O4r-QcPicFCzfelQ